# DirectoryInfo, FileInfo and very long path

Tags: c#, .net, fileinfo, directoryinfo, pathtoolongexception

I try to work with DirectoryInfo, FileInfo with very long path.

- I try use \\?\c:\long path (i got illegal caracter with fileInfo and DirectoryInfo)
- I try use file://c:/long path (i got uri not supported)

Can i use ~ in a path or something else.

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248816/c-call-win32-api-for-long-file-paths) but i would like to use another way that call a API. Is it any other solutions ?

There is an article from microsoft for use \\? in file path [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx)

The question is how can i work with very long path, and DirectoryInfo, and FileInfo for path who are more longer that 256 char

Comment: AlphaFS https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS may have bugs but works fine for me to use Directory.GetFiles(,,SearchOption.AllDirectories) . Download and built in VS2017 which produce dlls for NetFx45/46/47/20, used in VS2019, nice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to resolve file path too long exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745215/best-way-to-resolve-file-path-too-long-exception)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the [Long Paths in .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx) [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2007/03/26/long-paths-in-net-part-2-of-3-long-path-workarounds-kim-hamilton.aspx) [series](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/07/07/long-paths-in-net-part-3-of-3-redux-kim-hamilton.aspx), it looks like going to the Win32 API through P/Invoke is the only solution at the moment, other than restructuring your directories so that you don't hit the limit.

Answer (score 13):

The Library is available again [on this location.](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-17cc7893)

[This is a .NET Library](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-17cc7893) written against .NET Framework 2.0 and can be used to
 access very long folder and files from a .NET application.

Since the .NET Framework does not support long filenames :-(
 I had to write a library that calls the WIN32 API and wraps those
 functions like `System.IO`.  While it is not a complete replica of the
 `System.IO` it does have most objects and functions available.

`Delimon.Win32.IO` replaces basic file functions of `System.IO`
 with long path names support for characters up to 32,767 Characters
 So bye bye `MAX_PATH` problem

Did you ever run into this problem?

`System.IO.PathTooLongException`was unhandled.

Message:

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: Delimon.Win32.IO seems to be close sourced from a company. AlphaFS https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS may have bugs but works fine for me to use Directory.GetFiles(,,SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Answer (score 6):

The **[Delimon.Win32.I​O Library (V4.0)](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-V40-7ff6b16c)** is also available, it is written against .NET Framework 4.0 and can be used either on x86 & x64 systems.

Comment: Delimon.Win32.IO seems to be close sourced from a company. AlphaFS https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS may have bugs but works fine for me to use Directory.GetFiles(,,SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Answer (score 5):

A way I solved this issue in the past was using the library from Delimon called Delimon.Win32.IO.  It looks like his site http://www.delimon.be is down at the moment.  But I had used it on a project in the past and it worked like a champ.  I can try to track it down for you later this evening or just try to find a valid link to it somewhere via google.  Cheers.  Here's another link talking discussing this issue.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/2541a9b9-acd7-4338-89b1-dfc0408e41b5

Answer (score 1):

As of .NET 4.6.2, this issue can be resolved with a change to the local machine's group policy, allowing for long paths on Win 10+ and Server 2016+.

Tested and confirmed.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: Did you restart the PC after making the changes? Are you sure the group policy you changed is being applied to your user?

Comment: Yes. Still did not work for me after a reboot (Windows Server LTSC 2022). I ended up using AlphaFS ‍♂️