# Strange behavior from .NET regarding file paths

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file-io, pathname

I couldn't find any information on this through professor Google, so here I am. Take the given path name and paste it into Windows Explorer. I stumbled across this after discovering bug in my code that generated the paths with an extra '.' in the path name before a directory `\` separator...

```
@"C:\\pathto.\file.ext"
```

In code, .NET will accept the path when calling `File.Create` and a file will be generated, but at this path:

```
@"C:\\pathto\file.ext"
```

Copying `C:\\pathto.\file.ext` into Windows Explorer's address bar and watch the '.' disappear and take you to `C:\\pathto\file.ext`

Is it normal behavior for .NET and Windows to  It's not causing an issue because the '.' is being removed by both .NET and Windows when passed into file operations. The real issue is that all the files in the DB have filenames with a '.\', but exists in paths that do not have a '.\'... and `File.Exists()` works too, although the path is not the 'real' physical location...

What's going on here?

Comment: First, you can make it easier to copy and paste paths by using, eg. `@"C:\Users\Matt"` format (a 'verbatim string literals').

Comment: Maybe Windows forbids filenames (and folders) beginning or ending with `.` ?

Comment: Yes this is normal. Try creating a folder that ends with a full stop does the same.

Comment: You know that `.` is shorthand for the current directory, just as `..` is shorthand for the parent directory, right? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Comment: @Colonel Not especially relevant since that only applies to the beginning of the path. It's perfectly possible to support path names ending in dots; Windows just chooses not to.

Comment: @ColonelPanic Starting with `.` is fine with Win32, but you can't use explorer to create such files. Those files are common when interacting with unix based software, such as `.git`, `.htaccess`,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "feature" of the Windows file system. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".

Answer (score 0):

All normal Windows APIs ignore/remove trailing dots in the file/folder names when regular path is passed in.

If you really need support for trailing dot you need to use `"\\?\"` prefixed paths and interop all calls yourself (as .Net does not support this file format). See [MSDN: Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx),  [How to delete a folder that name ended with a dot (".")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075753/how-to-delete-a-folder-that-name-ended-with-a-dot) and [You cannot delete a file or a folder on an NTFS file system volume](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=320081) for more info.

Here is related question showing how to PInvoke function that accepts long file path: [c# call Win32 API for long file paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248816/c-sharp-call-win32-api-for-long-file-paths)