# How to get final filename

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a problem with getting a final file name in c#.

For example:

If user types two filenames:

"asd." and "asd.."

or

"asd " and "asd  " (two spaces)

then method `Path.GetFileName` returns "asd.", "asd..", "asd ", "asd  " (two spaces).

After saving it on a hard drive (e.g. using StreamWriter), then there is only one file "asd"

How can I check the final name of the input file? I suppose there is a lot of other examples and I could never do it properly manually.

**Edit**:

I use it to compare two file names and GetFileName returns:
for a.txt - a.txt
for A.txt - A.txt

But after save it's the same file. The comparison must ignore case.

Comment: Show me your code, so that we can see that and help you

Comment: I don't think the close vote is justified. It is a legit question about programming and there really is no need for any example code. The question is quite clear: when for example a SaveFileDialog reports the filename as "ads..." and saves it, the file will be renamed by the OS to "ads". How can you determine that this has happened?

Comment: Interesting question. The behavior is not (obviously) documented in msdn's references. It's certainly possible to create a file with trailing spaces in its name as far as NTFS (or FAT32?) are concerned, I just did it in a cygwin shell. But the explorer appears to handle the filenames as the same file and refuses to rename it when I try to add a space ("source and destination are the same file"). Resembles the incoherent case handling which can bother Java developers under Windows.

Comment: @Adam You should really consider marking Ulugbek as the correct answer to your question, he really nailed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is interesting internal NormalizePath method in Path class in .Net. If you don't mind reflection, you can use it.

```
string fileName = "asd..";
MethodInfo normalizePathMathod = typeof(Path).GetMethod("NormalizePath", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(bool) }, null);
string normalizedFilePath = (string)normalizePathMathod.Invoke(null, new object[] { fileName, true });
string normalizedFileName = Path.GetFileName(normalizedFilePath);
```

Just found better solution, without reflection. Path.GetFullPath calls NormalizePath method. So we can change it to:

```
string fileName = "asd..";
string normalizedFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
string normalizedFileName = Path.GetFileName(normalizedFilePath);
```

Comment: Very nice, didn't think about it

Comment: Nice solution, especially the one without reflection!

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `FileStream` to open the file, then you can use the `FileStream.Name` property after the stream was opened to get the "final" filename.

A crude example:

```
SaveFileDialog sDlg = new SaveFileDialog();

if (sDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     // E.g., sDlg.FileName returns "myFile..."
     FileStream f = new FileStream(sDlg.FileName, FileMode.Create);
     Console.WriteLine(f.Name); // then f.Name will return "myFile"
     f.Close();
     Console.ReadLine();
}
sDlg.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 7 i cannot rename a file from test to test. (it reverts to test) so i think the renaming comes from the filesystem that enforces specific rules for files rather than .Net.

Even using interop calls you cannot create a file with trailing dots. I don't really think you can get the corrected filename from inside .Net.  [EDIT: In fact Ulugbek's answer shows a very good way to do it]

A solution may be to write a empty file with the name to a temporary directory and check what the resulting filename is before deleting it.

Here is some more information: [Strange behavior from .NET regarding file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642420/strange-behavior-from-net-regarding-file-paths)