# How do I force a maximum pathlength with more than 260 characters

Tags: c#

I have a problem with saving. I need to images which path's are longer than the 260 characters (Sadly they have to be this long. Not my idea!)

I found this one here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/03/26/long-paths-in-net-part-2-of-3-long-path-workarounds-kim-hamilton/

I tried the \?\ but it didn't work.

My path is: "\\?\D:\Temp1\Data\"
In this case Visual Studio says that there is an unknown escape sequence.

Code:

```
RootDir = "\\?\"+RootDir;
```

Exception: None. Visual Studio simply says there is an unknown escape sequenz

Then i tried @"\\?\D:\Temp1\Data"
Visual Studio says that there is a sign which is not allowed. I guess it is the "?"
Code:

```
RootDir = @"\\?\"+RootDir;
```

Exception: 
illegal character in  path.
Maybe this helps in this case: 
System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.CheckIllegalCharacters(String[] str)

And when I try it without the \\?\ there is the windows exception which says that the Path only allows 260 characters.

What mistake/s did i do?

I hope you can help me.

Best regards
Richard

What I have tried:

These links:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/03/26/long-paths-in-net-part-2-of-3-long-path-workarounds-kim-hamilton/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx

Comment: Seeing your _exact_ code and the corresponding exception for each case would be helpful.

Comment: You need to prepend `\\?\\`, not `\?\\`.

Comment: Sry, I did the \\?\ not the \?\. Stackoverflow swallowed one. I also changed it in the question

Comment: @Evosoul Please show your actual code, using the code formatting tools in the question editor - it won't swallow characters then, which is hugely important in this type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long path prefix has two slashes, not one

```
string longPath = @”\\?\” + fileName;
```

---

UDT:
Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188527/how-to-deal-with-files-with-a-name-longer-than-259-characters) and this [lib](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-17cc7893)

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248816/c-sharp-call-win32-api-for-long-file-paths)

According to these posts, you shoul use winAPI to handle long paths

Comment: Sry, I did the \\?\ not the \?\. Stackoverflow swallowed one. I changed it in the question

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you posted, you have to write the path with 2 backslashes before the question mark

So the path should look like this

```
@"\\?\D:\Temp1\Data"
```

Or This

```
"\\?\D:\Temp1\Data"
```

Comment: Sry, I did the \\?\ not the \?\. Stackoverflow swallowed one. I changed it in the question

Comment: It is just a thought, have you tried using '\\\?\' ? I mean you will escape the backslash, then you will escape the question mark.